# Can Splunk OTEL collector scrape prometheus pushgateway endpoint?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, splunk, datadog

I have a system where Prometheus exporter pulls metrics and system pushes metrics to pushgateway.

I'm trying to get these metrics to Splunk and Datadog. Their docs mention that they scrape exporter. But does that imply they can scrape pushgateway endpoint too, since it is a prometheus endpoint?

I checked the docs

https://docs.splunk.com/Observability/gdi/opentelemetry/components/prometheus-receiver.html

https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/guide/prometheus-metrics/?tab=latestversion

They mention splunk collector and datadog agent can collect from exporter. Not sure if they can collect from pushgateway endpoint too.